# Defining both branch and tag in dependancy of package.json

Tags: json, git, npm, package.json

I'm using a Github repo as a dependancy in package.json in this format:

```
"dependencies": {
  "name": "https://github.com/user/repo.git#branch"
}
```

However, I'd also like to specify the `v1.4.0` tag from that branch. Is this possible, and how would I write it?

The [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies) explains using *either* a branch or a tag with `#`, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Something that might be useful is http://www.devthought.com/2012/02/17/npm-tricks/
defining partial or full commit id may bridge the gap of not being able define tag and branch in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your git dependencies can be the sha1 of the commit id.

http://www.devthought.com/2012/02/17/npm-tricks/